# JavaScript loop through multidimensional array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this variable:

```
let obj = {
    "aff_link": "https://event.2performant.com/events/click?ad_type=product_store&unique=83b281931&aff_code=d79aaed64&campaign_unique=2e49eab4f",
    "availability": true,
    "brand": "Casio",
    "date_add": 1666792631,
    "date_upd": 1666792631,
    "id": 78594,
    "price": 159.24,
    "product_type": "Ceasuri de mana",
    "title": "Ceas Casio CLASSIC LTP-1303L-7BVEF",
    "update_history": [
        {
            "id_feed": 108,
            "date_upd": 1666794541,
            "address" : [
                {
                    "present" :  "Dhanmondi 15",
                    "permanent" : "Gulshan 2"  
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "vgt_id": 0,
    "originalIndex": 0
};
```

Now, I have an array called:

```
let arr = [];
```

Now Using below function I loop through all the property and store it to variable `arr`.

```
function eachRecursive(obj) {
    for (var k in obj)  {
        if( k !== 'additional_image_link' ) {
            if (typeof obj[k] == "object" && obj[k] !== null) {
                eachRecursive(obj[k]);            
            } else {
                arr.push({
                    [k] : obj[k]
                })              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, usinge `console.log( arr )` I got this output:

```
[ { aff_link:
     'https://event.2performant.com/events/click?ad_type=product_store&unique=83b281931&aff_code=d79aaed64&campaign_unique=2e49eab4f' },
  { availability: true },
  { brand: 'Casio' },
  { date_add: 1666792631 },
  { date_upd: 1666792631 },
  { id: 78594 },
  { price: 159.24 },
  { product_type: 'Ceasuri de mana' },
  { title: 'Ceas Casio CLASSIC LTP-1303L-7BVEF' },
  { id_feed: 108 },
  { date_upd: 1666794541 },
  { present: 'Dhanmondi 15' },
  { permanent: 'Gulshan 2' },
  { vgt_id: 0 },
  { originalIndex: 0 } 
]
```

if you look at it you can see the there is no **key** called **update_history**, right ? I want that above output should contain  **update_history** as a key and the value should contain **id_feed**, **date_upd**, **present**, **permanent** with their corresponding value.

Can you help me please?

Comment: `update_history` is an object, so your code recurses through it (hence you have all the subkeys of `update_history` in your output)

Comment: @Nick any code would help me a lot!

Comment: How do you want `update_history ` to appear on `arr`? `[ { update_history: [ { id_feed: 108,  .. .} ]  }  ]`?

Comment: @BenAston my overall goal is to making a table where the key will be on left side of the table and all the values will be right side of the table. Value can be muti dimensional array. Help me if you have any better solutions

Comment: So `update_history` would effectively be a sub-table?

Comment: @BenAston No, it can be just a list item with value.

Comment: Please post an example showing exactly how you want `update_history` to look in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update_history` is an object (arrays are objects too), so your code recurses through it (hence you have all the subkeys of `update_history` in your output). You can prevent that by checking that `obj[k]` is *not* an array before recursing:

```js
let obj = {
    "aff_link": "https://event.2performant.com/events/click?ad_type=product_store&unique=83b281931&aff_code=d79aaed64&campaign_unique=2e49eab4f",
    "availability": true,
    "brand": "Casio",
    "date_add": 1666792631,
    "date_upd": 1666792631,
    "id": 78594,
    "price": 159.24,
    "product_type": "Ceasuri de mana",
    "title": "Ceas Casio CLASSIC LTP-1303L-7BVEF",
    "update_history": [
        {
            "id_feed": 108,
            "date_upd": 1666794541,
            "address" : [
                {
                    "present" :  "Dhanmondi 15",
                    "permanent" : "Gulshan 2"  
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "vgt_id": 0,
    "originalIndex": 0
};

let arr = [];

function eachRecursive(obj) {
    for (var k in obj)  {
        if( k !== 'additional_image_link' ) {
            if (typeof obj[k] == "object" && !Array.isArray(obj[k]) && obj[k] !== null) {
                eachRecursive(obj[k]);            
            } else {
                arr.push({
                    [k] : obj[k]
                })              
            }
        }
    }
}

eachRecursive(obj)

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

why you need recursion? if you need only update_history, pick him obj['update_history']

Comment: The overall goal is to making a table where the key will be on left side of the table and all the values will be right side of the table. Value can be muti dimensional array. Help me if you have any better solutions.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is create an html table with two columns (one for the `obj` keys and one for the `obj` values), here is a straightforward way to do it without needing recursion.

```js
const obj = {
    "aff_link": "https://event.2performant.com/events/click?ad_type=product_store&unique=83b281931&aff_code=d79aaed64&campaign_unique=2e49eab4f",
    "availability": true,
    "brand": "Casio",
    "date_add": 1666792631,
    "date_upd": 1666792631,
    "id": 78594,
    "price": 159.24,
    "product_type": "Ceasuri de mana",
    "title": "Ceas Casio CLASSIC LTP-1303L-7BVEF",
    "update_history": [
        {
            "id_feed": 108,
            "date_upd": 1666794541,
            "address" : [
                {
                    "present" :  "Dhanmondi 15",
                    "permanent" : "Gulshan 2"  
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "vgt_id": 0,
    "originalIndex": 0
};

let html = '';
html += '<table>';
for (let key in obj) {
  if (key === 'additional_image_link') continue;
  const val = obj[key];
  html += '<tr>';
  html +=   `<td>${key}</td>`;
  html +=   `<td>${JSON.stringify(val)}</td>`;
  html += '</tr>';
}
html += '</table>';

const outputElem = document.querySelector('#output');
outputElem.innerHTML = html;
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```